# Add a new listener inside an AddListener

Tags: java, swt, listener, zest

I'm creating a graph using the visualization toolkit Zest. I start by creating a graph then I add a node. I want to add to this node a mouse Double click event. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Is it because of the verification e.button == 3?

```
[...]
Graph graph = new Graph(parent, SWT.BORDER);

graph.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if (e.button == 3) {

            Menu menu = new Menu(parent);
            final MenuItem a1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.None);
            a1.setText("New Node");
            a1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                  GraphNode graphNode = new GraphNode(graph, SWT.NONE);
                                  graphNode.addListener(SWT.MouseDoubleClick, new Listener
                                         (
                                           @Override
                       public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                                               System.out.println("node created");});

                @Override
                public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
                    }
           }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MouseAdapter` instead of untyped `Listener`. And override its `mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)` method.

upd. how about

```
graph.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

     @Override
     public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0)
     {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, and I had this message :

The method addListener(int, Listener) in the type Widget is not applicable for the arguments (int, new MouseAdapter(){})

Comment: the one in the package : org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseListener ? it asks me to cast my GraphNode to a Ifigure !!

I tried it before, but I can't drag my node anymore! because I have to override the following methods :


- public void mouseDoubleClicked(org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseEvent arg0) {}

- public void mousePressed(org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseEvent arg0) {}

- public void mouseReleased(org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseEvent arg0) {}

Comment: I think, Alex meant the swt MouseAdapter class.